# How to find the location/folder of a report programmatically

Tags: apex, reporting

Been spending a long time trying to get all the info about a report programmatically using apex. One place I'm stuck at is how to get the folder name where the report is located in, and also its permissions, which means what role do you need in order to access this report. Take a look at this image for example.

[image]

Basically I just need to get the name "Folder for Testing", since that is where my report is located in.

I've tried using several methods from metadata api, reportResults, reportExtendedMetadata, but still no luck. I thought I would be able to do it using a SOQL query, but I'm still working on that. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what is known to you before starting off this logic? You only know the report name and then need to get the related info in your question?

Comment: Sorry, I should've added that I have other stuff about the report such as its ID, name, fields, columns, filters etc. This is just the last piece of info that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Report`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_report.htm) object has a **`FolderName`** field that should contain what you are looking for. As for how to run the query, I personally would just run it through the `Developer Console` (it has a `Query Editor` tab). You can add fields you care about to your `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT FolderName FROM Report WHERE DeveloperName = 'My_Report'
```